# im using selenium and after i run the code a new chrome window pop up the close by it self

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

brow=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

brow.get("https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=paython&a=hpb")
```

Comment: plz be patient with me im new :XD

Comment: i also tried to add this code chrome_opt.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
but also after loading the bage close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially, this is normal behavior--when you reach the end of your script the browser will close. Try the following and observe that the browser stays open as long as you tell it to.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_experimental_option("detach",True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=option)


driver.get('https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=paython&a=hpb')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[value="paython"]').send_keys("some stuff")
time.sleep(5)
```

Also, I'm not sure what syntax you used for `detach`; the following works for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_experimental_option("detach",True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=option)


driver.get('https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=paython&a=hpb')
```

Comment: Thx man, but the same issue happened

Comment: Which version of selenium are you using?

Comment: 4.4.3 and python 3.10.6

Comment: I realized what you're seeing is expected behavior since you're not doing anything after the `brow.get()`, the python script finishes and the browser closes. You can see my edited answer to perhaps get a better idea what's going on.

Comment: i solved it but i will try yor way also thx man

Comment: My second block of code is pretty much identical to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

it actually worked by this way

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?a=hpb%7Cspbg&q=python")
driver.maximize_window()
```